# How do I set the background color of the HTML tags to green all in one box

Tags: html, css

I need help setting the background color of the H2, H1, email text and button tags to green all in one box.

```css
.cursive {
  font-family: "Damion", cursive;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -610px; 
  left: 381px;    
}

.striking {
  font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: -610px; 
  left: 230px;
  line-height: 1.4;
      
}

.email {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;    
  position: relative;
  top: -610px; 
  left: 250px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-top: 12px;    
}

.button2 {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;    
  position: relative; 
  left: -20px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-top: 26px;
  padding-top: 20px;    
  width: 408px;
  height: 50px;    
  background-color: #4A4A4A;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;    
}
/* This is the CSS of the header i was trying to use to change the background: */
.header {
  background-color: #9DC20A;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 4px;    
}
```

```html
<div id="sign-up-section" class="banner">
  <div id="sign-up-cta">
    <div class="content center">
      <div class="header">
        <h2 class="cursive">Instant</h2>
        <h1 class="striking">FORMAT CAMERA</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="email">
        <span>
          Email us to request a demo and be in our <br>waiting list for the <strong>Febuary 2017</strong> release!
        </span>
        <div class="button2">Join the waiting list</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I tried to use the header declaration to change the background color, the color appeared underneath the image and when I tried to use the position to relative, and use the left and right properties to position the background color to where the tags where, it was on top of the tags, pushing it down.

So if someone can help me with this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: background-color isn't inherited. Could you explain what 'all in one box' means in this context? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is not showing anything. This is how you would change the background colors.

```
h1, h2, span, .button2 {
background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mwave317 pointed out I can't see the content in the code snippet.
Not sure if this is the issue, but I did notice you're targeting class `.header`  in your css, which only contains the h2 and h1 tags respectively in your html.

**CSS**

```
.header {
  background-color: #9DC20A;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 4px;    
}
```

**Targeting**

```
<div class="header">
   <h2 class="cursive">Instant</h2>
   <h1 class="striking">FORMAT CAMERA</h1>
</div>
```

So maybe you meant to target your `.content center` class which contains the `email` and `button2` classes?